# reading BMP BGR values, passing to glTexImage2D

Tags: c++, opengl, bmp

I've written a routine to read all pixel values from inside a BMP file to an array which I want to feed to glTexImage2D of openGL to turn it into a texture. Doing this I realised that the actual format of pixels inside BMP file is BGR and not RGB, so my array contains blue, green, red. As a result my final texture has its blue and red channels swapped comparing to the original bitmap.

This is how I call it:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, imgdata->width, imgdata->height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imgdata->pixdata);
```

Any workaround for this situation/wrong argument I'm passing? Only solution I can find right now is manually swap the RB values inside my array using a loop.

Answer (score 3):

Why not change the format of [glTexImage2D](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml) to GL_BGR.

Comment: Specifies the format of the pixel data.
                    The following symbolic values are accepted:
                    GL_RED,
                    GL_RG,
                    GL_RGB,
                    GL_BGR,
                    GL_RGBA, and
                    GL_BGRA.

Comment: I see it in the link you provided, but as I was reading from the red book, it wasn't in the list. Indeed, I set GR_BGR and it is marked as undeclared identifier

Comment: Ahh, of course... , always look in multiple sources. Anyway did it work?

Comment: I see, dunno, maybe you have an old version of something.

Answer (score 1):

> I set GR_BGR and it is marked as undeclared identifier

Then you're not using a [proper library for getting at OpenGL](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library). OpenGL's system-provided headers may or may not contain up-to-date functions and enumerators. So instead, you need to use one of those libraries to get at OpenGL. You should use these *instead* of `GL/gl.h`.

Once you're accessing OpenGL properly, the rest is simple. Use `GL_RGB` as your [pixel transfer format](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Transfer#Pixel_format).

Comment: could you help me understand what those Loading Libraries do? are they just a higher level interface to calling the openGL core, do they add functionality and which is the most up to date?